# update or delete output directory in dataflow google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a dataflow between **pubsub to cloud storage**. I have accidentally entered wrong output directory now I need to update the path of the output directory ? Can Anyone tell me how update the dataflow or how to delete it. I am creating this pipeline by UI provided by the google cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

In order to point to the correct output directory you will have to create a new job specifying the correct path to your Cloud Storage bucket. In order to delete the wrong one you will have to select the job in the UI and click on 'STOP'.

If you want you can also Stream messages from Pub/Sub to Cloud Storage with Cloud Dataflow using one of the available Client Libraries. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pubsub-dataflow) link you will find the code samples for Java and Python.